# How to put an image as a background in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, blogs

I encountered a problem while I tried to add an image to my blog. I was trying to put my image as a background and it did not work. How do I solve this.I also want it to cover the entirety of my blog's body.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
 
<style>
body {
  background-image: url('https://media.vanguardcommunications.net/blog-e1505840253663.jpg" alt="A blog" class="main-img');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
</style>


<h1>Posts</h1>

<ul>
{% for post in object_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'article-detail' post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a> - {{post.author.first_name}} {{post.author.last_name}} -  
        {{ post.post_date }} <small>

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            - <a href="{% url 'update_post' post.pk %}">(Edit)</a>

            <a href="{% url 'delete_post' post.pk %}">(Delete)</a>

        {% endif %}


    </small><br/>
    {{post.body|slice:":200" }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your background image url you mistakenly pasted the img tag url alongside the class and alt attribute just replace

```
 background-image: url('https://media.vanguardcommunications.net/blog-e1505840253663.jpg" alt="A blog" class="main-img');
```

with this

```
 background-image: url('https://media.vanguardcommunications.net/blog-e1505840253663.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these styles

```
body {
     background-image: url('https://media.vanguardcommunications.net/bloge1505840253663.jpg');
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
     background-attachment: fixed;
     height: 100vh;
     width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: When posting an answer please provide some details to the solution and not the only the solution itself

Comment: Inshallah, i will try. Thanks for your advice.